# R tidymodels / VIP variable importance determination

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels, vip

Via tidymodels and the vip package in R, I computed the variable importance. Code wise it would look like this:

```
rf_vi_fit %>%
pull_workflow_fit() %>%
vip(geom = "point") + 
labs(title = "Random forest variable importance")
```

Visually it would look something like this:

[image: Random forest variable importance]

However, what does the variable improtance actually entail? The variable importance can be based on multiple metrics, such as the gain in R-squared or the gini-loss, but I am unsure where the variable importance from the vip is based on. My other predictions has a variable importance of values around 3 to 4 instead of 0.005 as in this model.

I could not find what the variable importance is based on in the vip() documentation either.

Comment: As you're using the default settings, it should be: 
"the mean decrease in impurity (or gini importance) mechanism: At each split in each tree, the improvement in the split-criterion is the importance measure attributed to the splitting variable, and is accumulated over all the trees in the forest separately for each variable."

Source: https://blog.hwr-berlin.de/codeandstats/variable-importance-in-random-forests/

Weird how Tidymodels don't actually specify. But I think this is true.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to you inquiry lies in various sections in the vip documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vip/vip.pdf.

The `vip()` function is a wrapper around `vi()` used to plot the variable importance scores. In the `vip()` documentation, the `...` argument is "Additional optional arguments to be passed on to `vi()`".

In the `vi()` function, there is an argument called `method`.

> method = c("model", "firm", "permute", "shap")
> Character  string  specifying  the  type  of  variable  importance  (VI)  to  compute.  Current  options  are:
> "model" (the  default),  for  model-specific  VI  scores  (see `vi_model()` for details).
> "firm", for variance-based VI scores (see `vi_firm()` for
> details).
> "permute", for permutation-based VI scores (see `vi_permute` for details).
> "shap", for Shapley-based VI scores.
> For more details on the variance-based methods, see Greenwell et al. (2018) and Scholbeck et al. (2019).

Then, if you check the documentation of `vi_models()`, it describes in details the model-specific VI score for each type of model. Below is an excerpt describing RandomForest model specific importance.

> Random forests typically provide two measures of variable importance.
> The first measure is computed from permuting out-of-bag (OOB) data: for each tree, the prediction error on the OOB portion of the data is recorded (error rate for classification and MSE for regression).  Then the same is done after permuting each predictor variable.  The difference between the two are then averaged over all trees in the forest, and normalized by the standard deviation of the differences.  If the standard deviation of the differences is equal to 0 for a variable, the division is not done (but the average is almost always equal to 0 in that case). See importance for details, including additional arguments that can be passed via the ... argument.
> The second measure is the total decrease in node impurities from splitting on the variable, averaged over all trees.  For classification, the node impurity is measured by the Gini index. For regression, it is measured by residual sum of squares. See importance for details.